# How can I multiply negative numbers using the VVM program editor?

Tags: assembly, multiplication, little-man-computer, vvm

How can I multiply negative numbers using only some functions in [vvm](/questions/tagged/vvm) like `INP`, `STO`, `LDA`, `BR`, `BRP`, `SUB`, `ADD`, and `OUT`?

My code can multiply positive numbers, but it does not work correctly if the second input is negative or zero:

```
in
sto 99
in
sto 98
lda 97
add 99
sto 97 
lda 98 
sub 90
sto 98
lda 98
brz 13
br 04
lda 97
out
hlt
*90
dat 001
```

When the second input is zero or less, the program keeps looping and eventually hits a "Data value out of range (1000)" error at `add 99`, meaning the result exceeded 999.

I'm stuck, I don't know how to fix this. I feel like I need to convert the incoming negative inputs to positive and multiply them like that, but I don't know how to do this and whether it will solve the problem.

How can I make it work for non-positive values for the second input?

Comment: Write code that does `if (x < 0) x = 0 - x` and remember to negate the result in the end.

Comment: This looks like a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474379/how-can-i-multiply-negative-numbers-using-the-vvm-program-editor . Don't do that. If you changed anything, you still aren't showing what result you actually get, which is an important part of an [mcve].  https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ and https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: You need to modify the algorithm to handle negative and zero, but you don't have to think in assembly to do it.  Consider that the code does `int product = 0; do { product += a; while (--b != 0); }` Now, how would you upgrade that to handle negative/zero values of `b`?  This algorithm works if `b` is greater than zero, so what if `b` is zero how to handle?  What if `b` is less than zero, how to handle?

Comment: So, ok if the `b` value is zero, you can skip ahead to the end.  That's like putting an if-then around the loop, as follows: `int product = 0; if (b != 0) { do { product += a; while (--b != 0); } }`.  Can you see, how such if-then statement simply skips the loop when `b` is zero, leaving the product with the value zero, which is what you want when `b` is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your code does not work correctly when the second input is negative or zero.

For the case of zero: your code only checks whether the second input (which serves as a count down) becomes zero *after* having made one iteration of the loop. This check should better happen at the *start* of the loop so it is also performed at the very start.

For the case of a negative value: in this case you should "flip the sign" of both inputs, since `(-a)*(-b) == a*b`. To "flip" the sign, you can subtract the original value from 0, since `0-a == -a`.

It is a pity that the VVM does not support labels, and so you must use the correct numerical address in the operands. This can be a pain when a program is still under construction and those addresses likely change as you add more code. For that reason I would suggest leaving some gaps between code blocks, so that these jump-to addresses can be kept stable while you edit your code.

Code:

```
in
sto 99
in
brp 20     Normal case: start loop
// Remove sign from the second input (98)
sto 98
lda 91     Zero
sub 98
sto 98
// Toggle sign of the first input (99) to compensate
lda 91     Zero
sub 99
sto 99
lda 98     Prepare for loop
br  20     Start the loop
///////////////////// LOOP ////////////
*20
brz 40     Check immediately for 0
sto 98
lda 97
add 99
sto 97   
lda 98    
sub 90     Subtract one
br  20     Repeat
///////////////////// OUTPUT //////////
*40
lda 97
out
hlt
///////////////////// DATA ////////////
*90
dat 001
dat 000
```

#### Remarks:

The final `dat 000` is just to highlight that this memory address (91) is used by the program, and should have value 0. This is the default, and so it is not strictly necessary to include it.

The initial value for the result (at address 97) is also assumed to be 0 at the start of the program. This is a slightly different case, because this result will be updated by the program. But when the program is reloaded, all memory is first cleared to 000, so that we can assume the result to start with the value 0 at each run.

However, there is an option in the VVM, in the Execute menu, called *Reload @ Restart?*. It is on by default. If you turn it off, and restart the program after it has run at least once, then there will be no reload, and so the memory will stay in the state as it was after the preceding run. This means that the result at address 97 will in most cases not be 0. By consequence, the new run will *add* the new product to the result, giving maybe a surprising result -- it depends what you expect to happen in this case.

If you want every run to start with the value zero for the result, even when the above mentioned option is turned off, then explicitly initialise the result at the start of your program, by inserting these two instructions at the very top:

```
lda 91    Zero
sto 97    Initialise the result to 0
```

Comment: Thank yo so much, i understand completely. Leaving some gasp between code blocks is just a brilliant idea. Just one thing: what is the function of "dat 000"?

Comment: That zero at address 91 (`dat 000`) is used to negate values (`lda 91` loads zero into the accumulator).

Comment: but when i removed dat000, still code works fine.

Comment: Yes, it works without, and that is because all memory is set 000 when the program is loaded, so it is the default value. But I think it is better practice to explicitly have that `dat`, so it is clear we really intend to use that address for loading the value 000.

Comment: Having said that, the same really applies to the *result* (at address 97). It would be good to make clear it should start with the value 0 when the program starts. There is an option in VVM In the Execute menu, called "Reload @ Restart?", which is on by default. If you turn it off, then when you *restart* the program after a first run, memory will not be reset to 000, and so you would get "wrong" results... the values would be added to the already non-zero result at address 97. This is maybe too much to consider, but I just leave it here as a comment.